# How to prevent divide by ZERO in SQL when multiple tables using in arithmetic expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, zero, divide, arithmetic-expressions

I need to perform arithmetic operations using postgres tables. 
Formula and mapping are given by user and could be anything i.e a+b/(d-e) and there mapping is 'table1+table2/(table3-table4)'
I need to have created dynamic sql to evaluate the formula.
Currently I am using sql joins to achieve this, but not sure when divisor become ZERO and my query is blast.

Example Query a/b --> table1/table2:

```
select table1.timestamp as timestamp, table1.value/table2.value as value 
from table1 
inner join table2 
    ON table1.timestamp = table2.timestamp
```

Comment: Does 0 make sense as a value in your case? What do you want to happen if it's 0?

Comment: ignore record if divisor is zero, divisor could be any expression of tables

Comment: Do it in a stored procedure. Have proper error handling.

Comment: I typically wrap that into a `isnull()` function: `table1.value/isnull(table2.value,0)`

Answer (score 1):

If the user can enter the SQL expression, you have no chance. Catch the error and present it to the user.

If the user can be trusted with supplying an SQL expression, he/she should also be trusted with understanding the resulting error.

Keep in mind that a user who can enter a free-form SQL expression can do *anything*  they want with the database (think of subqueries).

Comment: Actually, formula is provided by user. In this I need to find out all the divisors :(

Comment: Oh, I missed that. In that case you have no chance. Catch the error and present it to the user. If the user can be trusted with supplying an SQL expression, he/she should also be trusted with understanding the resulting error.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds loke you just want to skip the records causing division by zero, like this:

```
select table1.timestamp as timestamp, table1.value/table2.value as value 
from table1 
inner join table2 
    ON table1.timestamp = table2.timestamp 
where t2.value!=0
```

If you want to allow nulls in table2.value you might want `where t2.value is distinct from 0` as where clause.

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: Would still cause trouble when table2.value is NULL, not clear if this is possible from the question

Comment: Change the where clause to ```where coalesce(t2.value,0)!=0``` to account for NULL.

Comment: Division by null does not cause an error. It is a perfectly valid statement - the result is null. Given that and depending business rules  you might actually want "nullif(t2.value,0)".

Comment: Yes.  You sometimes want nulls to come thru.  Might want to use is distinct from in those cases too.

Answer (score 0):

maximize the use if **postgresql** `if()` function.

```
select table1.timestamp as timestamp
    , if(table2.value > 0, table1.value/table2.value, 0) as value 
from table1 
inner join table2 
    ON table1.timestamp = table2.timestamp
```

you can also use `nullif()` function.

```
 select table1.timestamp as timestamp
        , table1.value/nullif(table2.value,0) as value 
    from table1 
    inner join table2 
        ON table1.timestamp = table2.timestamp
```

Comment: Actually, formula and table mapping are provided by user. In this I need to find out all the divisors

Comment: your 2nd query still results in a zero division